# How to update a GitSCM repo in a multiscm configuration in Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying to update a GitScm repo in a MultiScm configuration in Jenkins but can't find the right way to do it. Here is the code I have written so far:

```
if (jobScm.toString().contains("MultiSCM")) {
   def scms = jobScm.configuredSCMs
   for( scm in scms){
       job.branches = new hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM(uriName);
       job.save();
    }
}
```

Bit it throws me error.

Comment: error? Which error? Also which version of Git and Jenkins are you using?

Comment: It throws cannot update multiscm with a string. Git 2.6 and jenkins 1.648